# Cases in which the limiting value of a function $f(x)$ (as $x\to c$) is not equal to $f(c)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Can anyone state some cases such as mentioned in the title. I have tried to look for them on google and my textbook, but cant find any examples. And incidentally how can this fact be ever true? does it have something to with the function not  being defined at the limiting point $c$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & \text{ if } x = 0 \\
 0 & \text{ if } x\neq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Here
$$
f(0) = 1
$$
but
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0.
$$
I think your confusion comes from the fact that most functions you know (and can visualize) are *continuous* functions. Being continuous basically means that the graph is connected, that is, you can draw the graph without lifting the pen. For such functions you will always have that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c)$. So to give an example of a function that does not satisfy this formula, you have to think about a non-continuous (or *discontinuous function*). The graph of the function above follows the $x$-axis except at the one point where $x=0$. Here is it is equal to $1$. So there is a jump right at that point. The value of the function anywhere close to $x=0$ is $0$, and only at $x=0$ is the function not $0$.

Comment: Nitpick: $x \mapsto \sin \frac 1x$ with $f(0) = 0$ is a discontinuous function with a connected graph.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Sure, I was trying to bring it down to the OP's level.

Answer (score 2):

There are artificial examples created by piecewise definitions. (Richard Feynman once expressed surprise that anybody thought such things are *functions*.)  I'll try to give a more serious example: You are walking past a building with a conventional rectangular shape.  It is on your left.  The distance from you to the rightmost point on the building that you can see changes in a continuous manner until you pass the corner, and then it abruptly increases; it has a jump discontinuity.

Comment: Did Feynman really express surprise at the use of the word "function"? I was under the impression that such functions are used all the time in physics and engineering, with obvious physical interpretations, e.g., the Heaviside step function is a mathematical model of "flicking a switch". There's also those [potential wells](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Finite_Potential_Well_Symmetric.svg/325px-Finite_Potential_Well_Symmetric.svg.png) in quantum mechanics to simulate a particle in a box.

Comment: @WillR : Probably he would not have objected to all piecewise defined functions.  "Artificial" examples are what I had in mind.  I think someone showed Feynman a piecewise defined function of two real variables for which the mixed partial derivatives $ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial y}$ and $ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\,\partial x}$ failed to be equal at one point, and he said it was not a function. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x^2-2x & \text{ if } x \not= \frac12 \\
 3 & \text{ if } x= \frac12 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

[image]